# Cannot connect external Oracle database from inside Kubernetes

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, external

I'm deploying an App on k8s. But I cannot connect oracle from external machine.

I tried to connect directly via DBIP or try to connect via Serice Enpoint, but it doesn't work.

Please help me to solve that.

Here is database Info

```
  Database Ip: 192.168.1.25
  Port: 1521
```

Here is service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mydb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1521
    targetPort: 1521
    protocol: TCP
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mydb
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.1.25
    ports:
      - port: 1521
```

And connectionStr is

```
"User ID=test;Password=pwd;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mydb)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCLCDB)));";
```

Here is app_deloyment.yaml

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: web
      namespace: apptest
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          run: web
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            run: web
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: app-web
            image: app-web
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            env:
              - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
                value: "Staging"
            volumeMounts:
            - name: app-web-log
              mountPath: /app/Log
          volumes:
          - name: app-web-log
            hostPath:
              path: /log
              type: DirectoryOrCreate

    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: web-svc
      namespace: apptest
      labels:
        run: web
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - name: web
        protocol: TCP
        port: 80
        targetPort: 80
        nodePort: 30200
      selector:
        run: web
```

The output when I run cmd `kubectl logs core-dns-66bff467f8-htn5w -n kube-system`

```
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.7
linux/amd64, go1.13.6, da7f65b
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4425317009050045698.2183862687326411378. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.8:37732->8.8.8.8:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4425317009050045698.2183862687326411378. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.8:41292->8.8.8.8:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4425317009050045698.2183862687326411378. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.8:36947->8.8.8.8:53: read: no route to host
```

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu: do you have any idea about that?

Comment: oracle database is running outside kubernetes ? Are you able to connect to it directly without using kubernetes service? Is the issue only when connecting via kubernetes service?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu: yes, from Pod sh, I can ping to DB IP, and if I run directly a container without using k8s, it works. But with k8s, the message return of code is `Unable to resolve connect hostname`

Comment: Edit the question to add logs from coredns pod in `kube-system` namespace when you try to connect

Comment: Any reason you want to use a `Service` instead of directly connecting from the app pod to the database IP? Also, make sure your app's `Deployment`and the `mydb` `Service` are in the same namespace.

Comment: Can You also add Your deployment yaml manifest of Your app?

Comment: @BogdanL: I try to connect diretly via DB Ip address, but it doesn't work. I can ping Ip from inside app container but my app throw exeception `Unable to resolve connect hostname`. I don't know why. Anyway,  I'm sure my service and Deployment on same namespaces

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu: I added the output of logs coredns. Maybe it is problem with coredns, right?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?